# nginx matching wildcard subdomains without me asking to do this

Tags: nginx

I have the following server block

```
server{
   listen 80;
   server_name foo.domain.com;
   root /some/rails/app;
   passenger_enabled on;
}
```

However any subdomain under domain.com is matched using this block and is served by my rails app, so a.domain.com, nothing.domain.com, all are being sent to the rails app, how can I prevent this wildcard behavior which I didn't ask for ?

Answer (score 0):

You can drop all traffics that wasn't to a domain explicitly defined in another server configurations

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  deny all;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but why this behavior is happening although I didn't ask for it ?